# SUM(COUNT()) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm trying to work out how to make a column based on the count of one column multiplied by the number in another column of a joined table.

Below is what I've tried so far:

Attempt 1:

```
select a.course_id, sum(count(*)*c.FEE) as "Income", c.COURSE_NAME,c.STORE,c.VENUE,c.COURSE_LEVEL,c.COURSE_DATE,c.DURATION,c.FEE,c.STAFF 
from attendancecheck a
inner join course c
on a.course_id = c.course_id
group by a.course_id, c.COURSE_NAME,c.STORE,c.VENUE,c.COURSE_LEVEL,c.COURSE_DATE,c.DURATION,c.FEE,c.STAFF 
order by "Income"
```

I get error:    ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Attempt 2:

```
select a.course_id, sum(People_on_course * c.Fee) as "Income", c.COURSE_NAME,c.STORE,c.VENUE,c.COURSE_LEVEL,c.COURSE_DATE,c.DURATION,c.FEE,c.STAFF 
from (SELECT COUNT(a.participant_id) as People_on_course
from attendancecheck a)
inner join course c
on a.course_id = c.course_id
group by a.course_id, c.COURSE_NAME,c.STORE,c.VENUE,c.COURSE_LEVEL,c.COURSE_DATE,c.DURATION,c.FEE,c.STAFF
order by "Income"
```

I get error:    ORA-00904: "A"."COURSE_ID": invalid identifier

If someone can guide me in the correct direction on this, that would be great.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Please show table definitions and sample input and output data

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you summing already counted participants? Just use `count`, multiply by fee and that's all. Apply `left join` instead of `join` in case there are no participants for any course. You could also use subquery to count participants for each course.

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/VPSI45768)</sup>**

```
select c.course_id, count(a.participant_id) * c.fee as income, c.course_name, 
       c.store, c.venue, c.course_level, c.course_date, c.duration, c.fee, c.staff 
  from course c
  left join attendancecheck a on a.course_id = c.course_id
  group by c.course_id, c.course_name, c.store, c.venue, 
       c.course_level, c.course_date, c.duration, c.fee, c.staff 
  order by income
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!
I don't know why I had it in my head that I needed a SUM!

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the sum based on course table with the group by clause. Then join that based on course Id with attendancecheck .

```
select
  a.course_id, c."income", c.COURSE_NAME, c.STORE, c.VENUE, c.COURSE_LEVEL,
  c.COURSE_DATE, c.DURATION,c.FEE, c.STAFF
from attendancecheck a,
(
  select
    sum(People_on_course * c.Fee) as "Income",
    c.cource_id, c.COURSE_NAME, c.STORE, c.VENUE, c.COURSE_LEVEL, c.COURSE_DATE,
    c.DURATION, c.FEE, c.STAFF
  from course c
  group by
    c.course_id, c.COURSE_NAME, c.STORE, c.VENUE, c.COURSE_LEVEL, c.COURSE_DATE,
    c.DURATION, c.FEE, c.STAFF
) C
where a.course_id = c.course_id
order by c."Income" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select courses along with their total fees, for which you need the number of participants. So select courses and join the number of participants per course:

```
select
  c.course_id,
  c.fee * a.participants as income,
  c.course_name,
  c.store,
  c.venue,
  c.course_level,
  c.course_date,
  c.duration,
  c.fee,
  c.staff
from course c
join
(
  select course_id, count(*) as participants
  from attendancecheck
  group by course_id
) a on a.course_id = c.course_id
order by income;
```